# Bing Maps v8 - How to set tolerances (tl) or remove it, using DirectionsManager module?

Tags: maps, bing, bing-api, bing-maps

The code below generates an URL jsonp automatically to call Bing Maps REST API. But the tolerance parameter is defined by the module. How can I to define a custom tolerance to send?

> **Tolerance parameter (defined by module):** tl:4.5263499577364666e-7,0.0000036210799661891733,0.000028968639729513386,0.0002317491178361071,0.0018539929426888567,0.014831943541510854,0.11865554833208683
>
> **Full URL (generated by module):** https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/driving?key=AuohX_nFB0n9SozQUluVxFiJ3lHUMgNWDxt29NLz0fwqCKBZ32QJOwuh1lhtKaLK&o=json&jsonp=Microsoft.Maps.NetworkCallbacks.f98696&c=pt-BR&fi=true&wp.0=47.67683029174805,-122.1099624633789&wp.1=47.59977722167969,-122.33458709716797&tl=4.5263499577364666e-7,0.0000036210799661891733,0.000028968639729513386,0.0002317491178361071,0.0018539929426888567,0.014831943541510854,0.11865554833208683&optmz=timeWithTraffic&du=km&dt=9/30/2016%2010:54:00&tt=departure&maxSolns=3&rpo=Points

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
   credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
   center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.606209, -122.332071),
   zoom: 12
});

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {
    var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

    // Set Route Mode to driving
    directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });

    var waypoint1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Redmond', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.67683029174805, -122.1099624633789) });
    var waypoint2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Seattle', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.59977722167969, -122.33458709716797) });

    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint1);
    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint2);

    // Set the element in which the itinerary will be rendered
    directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('printoutPanel') });
    directionsManager.calculateDirections();
});
```

Bing Maps DirectionsManager Docs:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt748655.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the tolerances, nor is there any need to. The smallest tolerance value in the default setting will return all coordinates that the routing service provides for the route. If anything, I'm going to see if I can have the tolerance value removed all together since the performance of V8 shapes has drastically improved since the directions functionality was created.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in my case, the tolerance removes some coordinates from my itineraryItems object. I need all the coordinates to calculate (lat, lng) position every 3km from the route, to add pushpin.

When I use the route itineraryItems object  coordinates, the distance calculator crashes, when distant drag points exists

 ( eg:  O---- 3km ----O---- 3km ----O---- 3km ----O )  

Do you know somehow I get the coordinates, from REST api jsonp response via DirectionsManager? .resourceSets["0"].resources["0"].routePath.line.coordinates

Comment: Itinerary items and tolerance have nothing to do with each other. Tolerance returns multiple resolutions of the route path. V8 currently doesn't expose the route path data (only draws it). This will be exposed in one of the upcoming updates in a month or two. You can call the REST API directly if you need this now. You wouldn't use the Directions manager to call that API directly though. Here is a code sample from V7 that calls the REST services directly. This will work in v8. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427607.aspx

Comment: Exactly. That's what I did. Thanks a lot for the help!